# ERROR - The sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with Unity and im getting the same error while opening any project so i think its something wrong with the .NET extension of VS Code

```
[Error - 10:45:43 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Exception thrown while loading c:\UnityProjects\Awesome Pea 3\Assembly-CSharp.csproj StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: The sequence contains no elements
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](RequestId id, String targetName, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, IReadOnlyList`1 positionalArgumentDeclaredTypes, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 namedArgumentDeclaredTypes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isParameterObject)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.HostWorkspace.LanguageServerProjectSystem.LoadOrReloadProjectAsync(ProjectToLoad projectToLoad, BuildHostProcessManager buildHostProcessManager, BuildHost inProcessBuildHost, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Features/LanguageServer/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer/HostWorkspace/LanguageServerProjectSystem.cs:line 241
RPC server exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: The sequence contains no elements
      в System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
      в Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild.BuildHost.BuildHost.EnsureMSBuildLoaded(String projectFilePath)
      в Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild.BuildHost.BuildHost.IsProjectFileSupportedAsync(String projectFilePath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I found many similar issues, but they were always solved by not using the First() function in System.Linq. But I don't use this function anywhere, and the error occurs on literally any project so its not code issue. I've tried deleting the .csproj and .sln files, but that doesn't help either

Comment: Can we see your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Seems to be an issue with the latest version of the C# extension for VS Code (v2.3.27). Solved it by downgrading to v2.1.2.

Comment: if you're able to provide a [mre], feel free to suggest an edit to the question post to add it. Helping other people reproduce the problem helps better answers come.